# Collect all (which are true) in the if function

Tags: php

I have prepared some variable in a conditional function here.

```
<?php
if($one !== "")
    {
        $array = "Inner Join One on One.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($two !== "")
    {
        $array = "Inner Join Two on Two.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($three !== "")
    {
        $array = "Inner Join Three on Three.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($four !== "")
    {
        $array = "Inner Join Four on Four.id = Number.id"; 
    }
?>
```

---

---

Now I want to check **what it is needed to join**. I want to **collect all (which are true) in the if function**.

I hope anybody understand what I am trying to do here. And thanks in advance for that help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with -

```
$array = array();
if($one !== "")
    {
        $array[] = "Inner Join One on One.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($two !== "")
    {
        $array[] = "Inner Join Two on Two.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($three !== "")
    {
        $array[] = "Inner Join Three on Three.id = Number.id"; 
    }

if($four !== "")
    {
        $array[] = "Inner Join Four on Four.id = Number.id"; 
    }

$str = implode(" ", $array); // Can use other delimiters. here it is blankspace
```